# Count the number of times a value from one dataframe has repeated in another dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have 3 dataframes say A, B and C with a common column 'com_col' in all three dataframes. I want to create a new column called 'com_col_occurrences' in B which should be calculated as below. For each value in 'com_col in dataframe B, check whether the value is available in A or not. If it is available then return the number of times the value has occurred in A. If it is not, then check in C whether it is available or not and if it is then return the number of times it has repeated. Please tell me how to write a function for this in Pandas. Please find below the sample code which demonstrates the problem.

```
import pandas as pd 

#Given dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'comm_col': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'comm_col': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'comm_col':['A', 'A', 'D', 'E']})  

# The value 'A' from df2 occurs in df1 twice. Hence the output is 2. 
#Similarly for 'B' the  output is 2. 'C' doesn't occur in any of the 
#dataframes. Hence the output is 0
# 'D' and 'E' occur don't occur in df1 but occur in df3 once. Hence 
#the output for  'D' and 'E' should be 1

#Output should be as shown below
df2['comm_col_occurrences'] = [2, 2, 0, 1, 1]

Output:

**df1**
         comm_col
0        A
1        B
2        B
3        A

**df3**
         comm_col
0        A
1        A
2        D
3        E

**df2**

         comm_col  
0        A         
1        B         
2        C         
3        D         
4        E  

**Output**
     comm_col  comm_col_occurrences
0        A                     2
1        B                     2
2        C                     0
3        D                     1
4        E                     1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE]?

Comment: Yeah Sure. Just give me a while

Comment: import pandas as pd 

#Given dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'comm_col': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'comm_col': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'comm_col':['A', 'A', 'D', 'E']})

# The value 'A' from df2 occurs in df1 twice. Hence the output is 2. #Similarly for 'B' the  output is 2. 'C' doesn't occur in any of the #dataframes. Hence the output is 0
# 'D' and 'E' occur don't occur in df1 but occur in df3 once. Hence the output for 
# 'D' and 'E' should be 1

#Output should be as shown below
df2['comm_col_occurrences'] = [2, 2, 0, 1, 1]

Comment: Can you post this in the question with formatting?

Comment: @HarvIpan Is the question clear now ? Please let me know.

Comment: `C` occurs in `df2`, why is it 0?

Comment: We are checking whether the values from df2 occur in df1 or df3. First we should check whether it is available in df1 or not. If its available then we should check how many times it is repeated df1. If it is not available in df1, then check in df3 and do the same. In the above example C from df2 is not present in df1 or df3. Hence the output is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({
    'df1':df1['comm_col'].value_counts(),
    'df2':df2['comm_col'].value_counts(),
    'df3':df3['comm_col'].value_counts()
})
result['comm_col_occurrences'] = np.nan
result.loc[result['df1'].notnull(), 'comm_col_occurrences'] = result['df1']
result.loc[result['df3'].notnull(), 'comm_col_occurrences'] = result['df3']
result['comm_col'] = result['comm_col'].fillna(0)
result = result.drop(['df1', 'df2', 'df3'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    comm_col  comm_col_occurrences
0        A                   2.0
1        B                   2.0
2        C                   0.0
3        D                   1.0
4        E                   1.0
```